# How to include a header on a ToC page

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I am using the following code template by ShareLatex to get a header on every page of my report.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Share\LaTeX}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
```

But when trying to create a Table of Contents, this header wont show on my ToC page.

```
\tableofcontents
\newpage
```

What can I do? Note that my understanding of LaTex is very limited. I need an  easy customizable template so that I can just copy paste into my document.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman [a4paper, 11]{report}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely using a documentclass in which `\tableofcontents` is setting a `\pagestyle`. E.g. in `\documentclass{report}`, `\tableofcontents` invokes the `\chapter`-command, which in turn invokes `\thispagestyle{plain}`.

**Edit**: As @essd points out, my old answer will not work if you have multiple pages of table of contents, so I could suggest the following workaround instead where we redefine the plain style:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Redefine plain style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \rhead[R]{Share\LaTeX}
    \lhead[L]{Guides and tutorials}
    \rfoot[R]{Page \thepage}
}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \section{A}
\end{document}
```

The drawback with this would be that anywhere your report wants to set the pagestyle to `plain`, it will have headers. To work around this, you could do a rather ad-hoc work around by redefining the `\chapter` command temporarily:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Share\LaTeX}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\begin{document}
    \bgroup % \bgroup and \egroup is so 
            % that the \chapter command gets 
            % defined to what it was before
    \makeatletter
    % HEADS UP! This approach would only work for the report class
    \renewcommand\chapter{%
      % Same definition as in report.cls, but without the
      % \thispagestyle{plain} command
      \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
      \global\@topnum\z@%
      \@afterindentfalse%
      \secdef\@chapter\@schapter%
     }
    \makeatother
    \tableofcontents
    \egroup
    \clearpage
    \section{A}
    \chapter{2, alif}
\end{document}
```

### Old answer:

To work around this, you just have to overwrite this by e.g. writing `\thispagestyle{fancy}` right after `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Share\LaTeX}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{fancy} %<- Add this right after \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \section{A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will not work if there are 2 or more TOC pages: `\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{fancy}` sets the style of the last TOC page to `fancy`.

Comment: @essd Good point!

Answer (score 2):

If header and footer of page style `plain` should be the same as `fancy` you can use page style `fancyplain`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}% <- changed
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{Share\LaTeX}
\fancyhead[L]{Guides and tutorials}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand\plainheadrulewidth{.4pt}% <- added
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]